# Is reserved VM allocated for each web site in Windows Azure Web Sites?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

For using custom DNS, I want to switch from shared mode to reserved mode for 2 of my Windows Azure Web sites. These sites have low traffic and custom dns is the only reason to upgrade from shared to reserved.

What I am wondering is that when I switch to reserved mode for 2 of my sites, whether azure allocates 2 small VM instances (one for each) or do they share a common small VM (single) ?

If separate VM is dedicated for each web site, is not it quite expensive ? 57$ for each of them just to have custom DNS ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you upgrade one website to a reserved instance you'll get a notification like this one, requiring you to upgrade **all your sites in the current region** to reserved mode:

[image]

In my example I have 2 websites in the North Europe region, both instances will be upgraded to reserved model. You'll get 1 instance containing all your websites for that region. If you reach a point where you want to improve performance (let's say you have 100 sites), you can simply add new instances to the reserved capacity (this can be done in the **scale** menu).

Comment: thank you very much. having single VM containing all sites make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there are only two modes - Free/Shared and Reserved, and yes if you want to use Custom Domain, you must upgrade to Reserved mode. This will change soon when we roll out the new introduction of "Shared" mode. This new "Shared" mode will support Custom Domain. Please check back soon.